# How To Delete Line Breaks Within Certain Cell Of Word Table

Tags: vba, ms-word

I am currently having trouble with my VBA code. I am currently working on a useform that once completed fills in all the details for an email so it is ready to be sent. I have all the code working perfectly and everything is working okay except for 1 little thing:

In my code I have a `Case` where if you select a certain option it deletes rows of a table. The `Case` works fine but for some reason it leaves 4 line breaks after at the end. I wondered if there was anyway to delete these.

Code for the Case is below:

```
Select Case .Range("B6")
        Case ""
            MyDoc.tables(2).Cell(1, 1).Range.Text = VBA.Replace(MyDoc.tables(2).Cell(1, 1).Range.Text, "[Name]", .Range("B4"))

            MyDoc.tables(3).Cell(1, 1).Range.Text = VBA.Replace(MyDoc.tables(3).Cell(1, 1).Range.Text, "[Policy]", .Range("B9"))
            MyDoc.tables(3).Cell(1, 1).Range.Text = VBA.Replace(MyDoc.tables(3).Cell(1, 1).Range.Text, "[RenewalDate]", .Range("B10"))
            MyDoc.tables(3).Cell(1, 1).Range.Text = VBA.Replace(MyDoc.tables(3).Cell(1, 1).Range.Text, "[Insurer]", .Range("B11"))
            MyDoc.tables(3).Cell(1, 1).Range.Text = VBA.Replace(MyDoc.tables(3).Cell(1, 1).Range.Text, "[Premium]", .Range("B12"))
            MyDoc.tables(3).Rows(3).Delete
            MyDoc.tables(3).Rows(2).Delete

            MyDoc.tables(4).Cell(1, 1).Range.Text = VBA.Replace(MyDoc.tables(4).Cell(1, 1).Range.Text, "[Differences]", .Range("B14"))
            MyDoc.tables(4).Cell(5, 1).Range.Text = VBA.Replace(MyDoc.tables(4).Cell(5, 1).Range.Text, "[Current]", .Range("B7"))
            MyDoc.tables(4).Cell(7, 1).Range.Text = VBA.Replace(MyDoc.tables(4).Cell(7, 1).Range.Text, "[Alternate]", .Range("B8"))
            MyDoc.tables(4).Cell(8, 1).Range.Text = VBA.Replace(MyDoc.tables(4).Cell(8, 1).Range.Text, "[NM]", .Range("B43"))
            MyDoc.tables(4).Cell(8, 1).Range.Text = VBA.Replace(MyDoc.tables(4).Cell(8, 1).Range.Text, "[InAd]", .Range("B44"))
            MyDoc.tables(4).Cell(8, 1).Range.Text = VBA.Replace(MyDoc.tables(4).Cell(8, 1).Range.Text, "[BD]", .Range("B45"))
            MyDoc.tables(4).Cell(8, 1).Range.Text = VBA.Replace(MyDoc.tables(4).Cell(8, 1).Range.Text, "[Turn]", .Range("B46"))
            MyDoc.tables(4).Cell(8, 1).Range.Text = VBA.Replace(MyDoc.tables(4).Cell(8, 1).Range.Text, "[Wages]", .Range("B47"))

        Case "Existing Unable To Offer"
            MyDoc.tables(2).Cell(1, 1).Range.Text = VBA.Replace(MyDoc.tables(2).Cell(1, 1).Range.Text, "[Name]", .Range("B4"))

            MyDoc.tables(3).Cell(2, 1).Range.Text = VBA.Replace(MyDoc.tables(3).Cell(2, 1).Range.Text, "[Policy]", .Range("B9"))
            MyDoc.tables(3).Cell(2, 1).Range.Text = VBA.Replace(MyDoc.tables(3).Cell(2, 1).Range.Text, "[RenewalDate]", .Range("B10"))
            MyDoc.tables(3).Cell(2, 1).Range.Text = VBA.Replace(MyDoc.tables(3).Cell(2, 1).Range.Text, "[Insurer]", .Range("B11"))
            MyDoc.tables(3).Cell(2, 1).Range.Text = VBA.Replace(MyDoc.tables(3).Cell(2, 1).Range.Text, "[Premium]", .Range("B12"))
            MyDoc.tables(3).Rows(3).Delete
            MyDoc.tables(3).Rows(1).Delete

            MyDoc.tables(4).Cell(1, 1).Range.Text = VBA.Replace(MyDoc.tables(4).Cell(1, 1).Range.Text, "[Differences]", .Range("B14"))
            MyDoc.tables(4).Cell(5, 1).Range.Text = VBA.Replace(MyDoc.tables(4).Cell(5, 1).Range.Text, "[Current]", .Range("B7"))
            MyDoc.tables(4).Cell(7, 1).Range.Text = VBA.Replace(MyDoc.tables(4).Cell(7, 1).Range.Text, "[Alternate]", .Range("B8"))
            MyDoc.tables(4).Cell(8, 1).Range.Text = VBA.Replace(MyDoc.tables(4).Cell(8, 1).Range.Text, "[NM]", .Range("B43"))
            MyDoc.tables(4).Cell(8, 1).Range.Text = VBA.Replace(MyDoc.tables(4).Cell(8, 1).Range.Text, "[InAd]", .Range("B44"))
            MyDoc.tables(4).Cell(8, 1).Range.Text = VBA.Replace(MyDoc.tables(4).Cell(8, 1).Range.Text, "[BD]", .Range("B45"))
            MyDoc.tables(4).Cell(8, 1).Range.Text = VBA.Replace(MyDoc.tables(4).Cell(8, 1).Range.Text, "[Turn]", .Range("B46"))
            MyDoc.tables(4).Cell(8, 1).Range.Text = VBA.Replace(MyDoc.tables(4).Cell(8, 1).Range.Text, "[Wages]", .Range("B47"))

        Case "More Competitive Quotation"
            MyDoc.tables(2).Cell(1, 1).Range.Text = VBA.Replace(MyDoc.tables(2).Cell(1, 1).Range.Text, "[Name]", .Range("B4"))

            MyDoc.tables(3).Cell(3, 1).Range.Text = VBA.Replace(MyDoc.tables(3).Cell(3, 1).Range.Text, "[Policy]", .Range("B9"))
            MyDoc.tables(3).Cell(3, 1).Range.Text = VBA.Replace(MyDoc.tables(3).Cell(3, 1).Range.Text, "[RenewalDate]", .Range("B10"))
            MyDoc.tables(3).Cell(3, 1).Range.Text = VBA.Replace(MyDoc.tables(3).Cell(3, 1).Range.Text, "[Insurer]", .Range("B11"))
            MyDoc.tables(3).Cell(3, 1).Range.Text = VBA.Replace(MyDoc.tables(3).Cell(3, 1).Range.Text, "[Premium]", .Range("B12"))
            MyDoc.tables(3).Rows(1).Delete
            MyDoc.tables(3).Rows(1).Delete

            MyDoc.tables(4).Cell(1, 1).Range.Text = VBA.Replace(MyDoc.tables(4).Cell(1, 1).Range.Text, "[Differences]", .Range("B14"))
            MyDoc.tables(4).Cell(5, 1).Range.Text = VBA.Replace(MyDoc.tables(4).Cell(5, 1).Range.Text, "[Current]", .Range("B7"))
            MyDoc.tables(4).Cell(7, 1).Range.Text = VBA.Replace(MyDoc.tables(4).Cell(7, 1).Range.Text, "[Alternate]", .Range("B8"))
            MyDoc.tables(4).Cell(8, 1).Range.Text = VBA.Replace(MyDoc.tables(4).Cell(8, 1).Range.Text, "[NM]", .Range("B43"))
            MyDoc.tables(4).Cell(8, 1).Range.Text = VBA.Replace(MyDoc.tables(4).Cell(8, 1).Range.Text, "[InAd]", .Range("B44"))
            MyDoc.tables(4).Cell(8, 1).Range.Text = VBA.Replace(MyDoc.tables(4).Cell(8, 1).Range.Text, "[BD]", .Range("B45"))
            MyDoc.tables(4).Cell(8, 1).Range.Text = VBA.Replace(MyDoc.tables(4).Cell(8, 1).Range.Text, "[Turn]", .Range("B46"))
            MyDoc.tables(4).Cell(8, 1).Range.Text = VBA.Replace(MyDoc.tables(4).Cell(8, 1).Range.Text, "[Wages]", .Range("B47"))

    End Select
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: It's not clear which line produces the issue? Go through your code step by step using F8 and debug your values to see where the issue happens.

Comment: the issue happens within table 3, after the rows are deleted as the rest of the code for this works fine

Comment: Could you please upload screen shots of the table before running the macro and of the result you're getting, indicating the "empty lines". Make sure you turn on the display of non-printing characters so we can see what these "empty lines" are.

Comment: Hi, Sorry for the delay, image is http://tinypic.com/r/2ugpftc/9. The image shows the email before, then the userform which is completed and it decides which one to display from the 3rd question and then the email after. Hope this helps